# Conditional form drop-downs and outputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, input

I created a form that produces a custom sentence based on a user's input. I want to make a conditional input thus leading to a conditional addition to the sentence. If the user selects "Okay" (id="z4") for the vehicle condition, I want the "Why?" (id="z5") dropdown menu to appear. Then after he or she selects one of the options from the "Why?" dropdown that is added to the sentence.

For example-

1. The user inputs 2012 Honda Civic, 96,000, red, good. The output sentence is as follows: Up for sale is a **2012 Honda Civic**  with **96,000** miles. It is finished in **red**. It is in **good shape**.
2. The user inputs 2012 Honda Civic, 96,000, red, okay, dents. The output sentence is as follows: Up for sale is a **2012 Honda Civic**  with **96,000** miles. It is finished in **red**. It is in **okay shape** because it has some **dents**.

Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Experiment</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";
    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();
    } else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
      alert("Mileage is needed");
    } else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
      alert("Exterior color is needed");
    } else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
      const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
      const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
      const input4 = document.getElementById("z4").value;

      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
        + input3 + ". It is in " + input4 + " shape.";

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }

  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
  }
 </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="hide()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100"></td>
        <td> <select name="condition" id="z4"> <option value="" disabled selected>Condition</option> <option value="excellent">Excellent</option> <option value="good">Good</option> <option value="okay">Okay</option></select></td>
        <td> <select name="condition" id="z5"> <option value="" disabled selected>Why?</option> <option value="scratches">Scratches</option> <option value="dents">Dents</option> <option value="mechanical issues">Mechanical Issues</option></select></td>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1">

  </textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you need help with, specifically? It looks like you know how to build a sentence based on the user's input, and it also looks like you know how to use `if` statements. Are you having some kind of a problem? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question.

Comment: I figured out how to create a statement to make the condition dropdown appear only if a certain selection ("okay") is made. However, I can't figure out how to make the custom sentence conditional.